# Error updating database parameters in Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have never used an Amazon Lightsail database, the fact is that we recently migrated our database from local to the cloud and in one of the functionalities the following error occurs

[image: php error]

I found the solution in the following link

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-updating-database-parameters#get-database-parameters

This is the command I run to update the value, but it gives me the following error and I have no idea what else to do.

```
aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name bai --parameters "parameterName=sort_buffer_size,parameterValue=5556000000,applyMethod=inmediate"

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the UpdateRelationalDatabaseParameters operation:
```

Any solution please. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, sorry I hadn't looked at the parameter properties. I'll leave the solution anyway in case it happens to someone else.

[image: solution]